# Lucene 4.0 Index writer - creating single index

Tags: java, search, text, lucene

I am trying to implement simplest lucene search. I followed [this](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=461633&seqNum=2) as my starting point.

I can understand the sample code :

```
public static void indexHotel(Hotel hotel) throws IOException {
    IndexWriter writer = (IndexWriter) getIndexWriter(false);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new Field("id", hotel.getId(), Field.Store.YES,
    Field.Index.NO));
    doc.add(new Field("name", hotel.getName(), Field.Store.YES,
    Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
    doc.add(new Field("city", hotel.getCity(), Field.Store.YES,
    Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
    doc.add(new Field("description", hotel.getDescription(),
    Field.Store.YES,
    Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
    String fullSearchableText = hotel.getName() + " " + hotel.getCity() + " " + hotel.getDescription();

    doc.add(new Field("content", fullSearchableText,
    Field.Store.NO,
    Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
    writer.addDocument(doc);
}
```

the thing i can't get in this code is what does `getIndexWriter(false)` do . this method is nowhere mentioned in the post i followed. moreover in another code block :

```
public void rebuildIndexes() throws IOException {
   //
   // Erase existing index
   //
   getIndexWriter(true);
   //
   // Index all hotel entries
   //
   Hotel[] hotels = HotelDatabase.getHotels();
   for(Hotel hotel: hotels) {
     indexHotel(hotel);
   }
   //
   // Don’t forget to close the index writer when done
   //
   closeIndexWriter();
 }
```

some undefined methods are used.

A bit confusing for beginner like me.

I want to create only one index . i think `getIndexWriter(true);` and `closeIndexWriter()` are some utility methods just to get `IndexWriter` but i can't make any assumption for what does that `true` in `getIndexWriter(true);` is used for.

By following some other post's iv'e got more confused regarding the creation of IndexWriter.

Can somebody please put me on the right path if i am doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well depending on where is your index (RAM or FileSystem) you can open different indexWriters.
Assuming that you are trying to write the index into the file system you should have something like this:

```
public static final Version luceneVersion = Version.LUCENE_40;

IndexWriter getIndexWriter(){

    Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File( INDEX_PATH ));

    IndexWriterConfig luceneConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(
                luceneVersion, new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion));

    return(new IndexWriter(indexDir, luceneConfig));
   }
```

Note the analyzer class 'StandardAnalyzer', you should choose the analyzer depending on the  application requirements. I reckon StandardAnalyzer is good enough for what you want to do.

The input argument maybe asks if a new writer should be created ?

Comment: Yeah, look at the article cited, page 2. It's fairly obvious that's their construction: IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter("index", new StandardAnalyzer(), true);  The true used to mean "create new index" and is absorbed into the more recent syntax amas talks about